# Matched elements from mongodb records

Tags: mongodb

Suppose I have following documents in my collection

```
{  
   "_id":ObjectId("562e7c594c12942f08fe4192"),
   "tags" : [ 
        {
            "tagName" : "fun",
            "created" : ISODate("2016-01-22T06:13:56.510Z")
        }, 
        {
            "tagName" : "cool",
            "created" : ISODate("2016-01-22T06:13:56.509Z")
        }, 
        {
            "tagName" : "good",
            "created" : ISODate("2016-01-22T06:13:56.509Z")
        }
    ]
},
{  
   "_id":ObjectId("562e7c594c12942f08fe4193"),
   "tags" : [ 
        {
            "tagName" : "super",
            "created" : ISODate("2016-01-22T06:13:56.509Z")
        }, 
        {
            "tagName" : "fun",
            "created" : ISODate("2016-01-22T06:13:56.509Z")
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to search relative tags and want to display tag array only.

How can I query to get the list of tag names?

Comment: Not sure what you mean here. Do you just want the "tags" array to display only the content of "tagName"? Or do you just want a "distinct" list of all values in "tagName" for the collection?

Comment: @BlakesSeven I just want tagName as array, which matches to my search string.

Comment: Still really unclear what you are expecting. Why is this not your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/retrieve-only-the-queried-element-in-an-object-array-in-mongodb-collection ? If you expect something different then please at least supply your sample query data and expected response.

Comment: Do you need output like  [ { "tagName" : "fun" }, {"tagName" : "cool" }] this?

Answer (score 1):

To only query a specific field in MongoDB you can use the find method with the projection parameter: 
https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/

```
db.test.find({}, {"tags.tagName":1,"_id":0}).pretty()
{
    "tags" : [
        {
            "tagName" : "fun"
        },
        {
            "tagName" : "cool"
        },
        {
            "tagName" : "good"
        }
    ]
}
```

The first parameter is blank `{}` because you don't have any query and the second parameter is your projection. With an embedded document you have to use the dot notation `"tags.tagName"`. The `"_id":0` to not display the `_id` field.